# Minimum number of generators of the product of a finite group with itself

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

For a finite group $G$, I define $d(G)$ to be

\begin{equation}
d(G)= \min\{|S|: S\subseteq G,\ <S>=G \}
\end{equation}

Now clearly, by the surjective projection map $\pi_1:G\times G\rightarrow G$, we have that $d(G) \leq d(G\times G)$.

Now the question is, can the inequality be proven to be strict for all finite groups? And if not,  can you find a finite group $G$ such that $d(G\times G) = d(G)$?

Comment: The alternating group $A_5$ has equality. For (much) more, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265260/how-many-generators-does-a-direct-product-of-alternating-groups-need